# Placeholder and IE != BFFs (Placeholder and IE9 not working)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, placeholder

So, I'm trying to get the placeholder attribute to work in IE9 and below.  However, I'm getting odd behavior (see screenshots below).

I found [this website](http://www.cssnewbie.com/cross-browser-support-for-html5-placeholder-text-in-forms/#.UkA8HYash8F) and decided to use the JS code below:

**JS:**

```
    // Checks browser support for the placeholder attribute
    jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
    test = document.createElement('input');
    if('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;
    });

    // Placeholder for IE
    $(function () {
        if(!$.support.placeholder) { 

            var active = document.activeElement;
            $(':text, textarea').focus(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                    $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
                }
            }).blur(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
                }
            });
            $(':text, textarea').blur();
            $(active).focus();
            $('form').submit(function () {
                $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() { $(this).val(''); });
            });
        }  

    });
```

**HTML:**

```
    <p>
        <label>To: </label>
        <input type="text"  id="toEmail" placeholder="Recipient's Email Address" />
    </p>       

    <p>
        <label>From:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fromName" placeholder="Your Name" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>From: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fromEmail" placeholder="Your Email Address" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Message:</label>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="5" id="messageEmail"></textarea>
    </p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hasPlaceholder {
    color: #999;
}
```

My website opens up a modal with a form in it.  However, when the modal is first opened, none of the placeholder text shows up:

[image: Initial State]

However, if I click into the text field, then click out of the text field, the placeholder text shows up.

[image: After Onblur of text field]

I'd like the text to show up immediately once the modal has been opened.  That's all really...

**FYI-** I suspect that it's possible the text doesn't initially appear because my modal is hidden initially.  How could I fix that if that is the case?

**NOTE:** I KNOW THAT PLUGINS EXIST.  I DON'T WANT TO USE PLUGINS.

Comment: Chain `.blur()` on the end after `.blur(function () {/* ... */})`, also, why aren't you caching `$(this)`?

Comment: @PaulS. I'm afraid that didn't work...

Comment: @PaulS. I suppose I could, but I'm using borrowed code, so I've done very few modifications to it.  If by caching `this` I can store the variable and have it injected into the modal, then I could see it's usefulness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my problem was completely unrelated to the code itself, but was a problem with the **placement** of the code.

I placed the JS code directly into the *index.html* file, when I should have placed it inside of a different *emailmodal.js* file.

I think the issue was the fact that the modal is initially hidden, therefore, when the JS runs, those text fields don't exist yet.  It's not until I open the modal and click into the text field, that those fields suddenly "exist".

You guys can correct me if I'm wrong, but my problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Change your jquery to this:

```
; (function ($) {
    $.fn.placehold = function (placeholderClassName) {
        var placeholderClassName = placeholderClassName || "placeholder",
            supported = $.fn.placehold.is_supported();

        function toggle() {
            for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                arguments[i].toggle();
            }
        }

        return supported ? this : this.each(function () {
            var $elem = $(this),
                placeholder_attr = $elem.attr("placeholder");

            if (placeholder_attr) {
                if ($elem.val() === "" || $elem.val() == placeholder_attr) {
                    $elem.addClass(placeholderClassName).val(placeholder_attr);
                }

                if ($elem.is(":password")) {
                    var $pwd_shiv = $("<input />", {
                        "class": $elem.attr("class") + " " + placeholderClassName,
                        "value": placeholder_attr
                    });

                    $pwd_shiv.bind("focus.placehold", function () {
                        toggle($elem, $pwd_shiv);
                        $elem.focus();
                    });

                    $elem.bind("blur.placehold", function () {
                        if ($elem.val() === "") {
                            toggle($elem, $pwd_shiv);
                        }
                    });

                    $elem.hide().after($pwd_shiv);
                }

                $elem.bind({
                    "focus.placehold": function () {
                        if ($elem.val() == placeholder_attr) {
                            $elem.removeClass(placeholderClassName).val("");
                        }
                    },
                    "blur.placehold": function () {
                        if ($elem.val() === "") {
                            $elem.addClass(placeholderClassName).val(placeholder_attr);
                        }
                    }
                });

                $elem.closest("form").bind("submit.placehold", function () {
                    if ($elem.val() == placeholder_attr) {
                        $elem.val("");
                    }

                    return true;
                });
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.placehold.is_supported = function () {
        return "placeholder" in document.createElement("input");
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then make the function work:

```
$("input, textarea").placehold("something-temporary");
```

Comment: Thanks for the new code.  I'll try this if my current code doesn't work, but first I want to see if I can get what I have to work.

Comment: np I always use this along with Modernizr so it works on IE7+ for placeholder